# what does "そんな心算ではありませんでした" means?

Tags: meaning

I saw on a pic that said this phrase in my language is " I didn't mean to do it " 
But when I google translate to English its said " It was not such a mental count " ???? So confused.

Comment: That proves how Google Translate is shaky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そんなつもりではありませんでした。

=It was not such an intention.

=My intention was not like it.

＝I didn't mean it. I didn't mean to do it.

つもり＝intention

The kanji for つもり is written as "心算," which is very difficult to read even for native Japanese speakers.

The kanji, 心, itself means "heart, mental."

The kanji, 算, itself means "count."

Therefore, Google translate was not clever enough and made such a mistake.

The correct thing is:

つもり＝心算＝intention.

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea 心算 could be read tsumori nor such reading is reported in several dictionaries I checked. However, it seems to be the case indeed: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%A9%8D%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A%E3%83%BB%E7%A9%8D%E3%82%8A%E3%83%BB%E5%BF%83%E7%AE%97-332073

Comment: Me, either. haha